# Cannot get Unit Test's thenReturn() value in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, testing, mocking

I have the following service and test methods:

ProductServiceImpl:

```
public List<ProductDTO> findAllByCategoryUuid(UUID categoryUuid) {

    // code omitted

    return result;
}
```

***ProductServiceImplTest:***

```
@Spy
@Autowired 
ProductServiceImpl productService;

@Mock
ProductRepository productRepository;

// ... other mock repositories
  

@Test
public void testFindAllByCategoryUuid() {

    UUID categoryUuid = UUID.randomUUID();

    final List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        // create product by setting "categoryUuid" and add to productList
    }
    when(productRepository.saveAll(productList)).thenReturn(productList); // ?


    List<ProductDTO> response = new ArrayList<>();
    doReturn(response).when(productService).findAllByCategoryUuid(categoryUuid); // ?
}
```

Although I create mock products with the correct `categoryUuid` relation, I cannot retrieve these mock products by the same `categoryUuid` and `findAllByCategoryUuid` method always returns empty list. So, how can I fix? And how should I use `when` and `doReturn` methods above properly?

Comment: What is your reason for using `@Spy`? Also, you probably need to use `@MockBean`. Finally, in most cases if you use constructor injection you don't need Spring for unit tests; just pass your mocks to the constructor of the class under test.

Comment: Why do you have `doReturn` on `productService`? Isn't that the object you are trying to test? Also your test makes no assertion. Which method is called on `productRepository` in `findAllByCategoryUuid`? Is it `saveAll`?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-  Why do not you post example by updating my code as answer?

Comment: @tgdavies Why do not you post example by updating my code as answer?

Comment: Because I don't know enough about what your code does to give you an answer. For instance, until I understand why you have chosen to use `doReturn(response).when(productService)...` I may well not really understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @tgdavies Regarding to `doReturn`, I had to rephrase `when.thenReturn()` because I got  "ArrayList cannot be returned by toString() toString() should return String" error. I think both of them can be used instead of the other.

Comment: My question isn't why you use `doReturn` instead of `when`, but why you are mocking the behaviour of the class under test.

Comment: Sorry, but I have no experience and in addition to that too confused with my project and the examples on the web. That's why I need you help by posting a proper way for my scenario. I am sure that it will be so useful for me and fix most of the confusion in my mind.

Answer (score 0):

You would normally do something like this:

```
public class ProductServiceImplTest {

  // create an actual instance of the class you want to test, with its dependencies supplied by mocks
  @InjectMocks
  ProductServiceImpl productService;

  // This will be injected into productService;
  @Mock
  ProductRepository productRepository;

  @Test
  public void testSomeAspectOfProductServiceImplBehaviour() {
    // tell the productRepository mock to respond as necessary for the test
    when(productRepository.something()).thenReturn(...);
    // call the method you want to test and check that the result is as expected
    assertThat(productService.someMethod(), Matchers.equalTo(...);
  }
}
```

Comment: Very useful explanations, voted up. On the other hand, if you have time, it would be really much more useful adding some example mock beans and their usages (beans that I need to set some of their properties and beans that just a mock bean).